# GDataXML stringValue vs. XMLString

Tags: ios, objective-c, gdataxml

See title. What's the difference between the return value of GDataElement instance methods:

```
-(NSString *) XMLString;
```

and

```
-(NSString *) stringValue;
```

Comment: You need to add more details to your question.

Comment: The method declarations don't provide readers with any more useful information. We want to see the work you've put in to answering this yourself. What does the output of the methods look like? What do the differences _seem_ to be? What causes your confusion about the differences? What does the relvant documentation say and why doesn't it answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLString returns the raw string representation of the node, and stringValue returns the value inside the tag, such as

```
<tag>this is string value</tag>.
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up.